# Why is simultaneity a requirement for the distance function of Galilean space?

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, symmetry, group-theory

At the end of Chapter 2 of his *Course in Mathematical Physics*, Szekeres discusses the notion of a symmetry group. I present my definition, adapted from his, here:

> We say that a transformation $g: X \to X$ (i.e. $g \in$ Transf($X$)) leaves the $Y_i$-valued function $F_i$ **invariant** if, for all $x \in X$, we have $F_i(x) = F_i(gx)$.We have used the shorthand $gx \equiv g(x)$ since $g \in$ Transf($X$) so that it’s (left) action on $G$ is trivially defined by $g \mapsto g$.

> We say that a transformation leaves a space $X$ equipped with a set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ **invariant** if it leaves each $F_i \in \mathcal{F}$ invariant.

> The set of all transformations $g$ which leave $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ invariant is called the symmetry group of that space. I will use the notation Sym$(X,\mathcal{F})$ for this group.

In general, the "functions on the space" may actually be functions of, e.g., Cartesian products of the underlying set (or subsets of the powerset).

Later, Szekeres defines Galilean space:

> Define an event to be a point of $\mathbb{R}^4$ characterized by four coordinates $(x, y, z, t)$. Define Galilean space $\mathbb{G}^4$ to be the space of events with a structure consisting of three functions defined thereon:
>
> 1. Time intervals $\Delta t := t_2 − t_1$.
> 2. The spatial distance $\Delta s = |\mathbf{r}_2 − \mathbf{r}_1|$ between any pair of simultaneous events (events
>    having the same time coordinate, $t_1 = t_2$).
> 3. Motions of inertial (free) particles, otherwise known as rectilinear motions,
>    $\mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{u}t + \mathbf{r}_0$, (2.19) where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{r}_0$ are arbitrary constant vectors.

Finally, he adds the following discussion:

> Note that only the distance between simultaneous events is relevant. A simple example should make this clear. Consider a train travelling with uniform velocity v between two stations A and B. In the frame of an observer who stays at A the distance between the (non-simultaneous) events E1 = ‘train leaving A’ and E2 = ‘train arriving at B’ is clearly $d = vt$, where t is the time of the journey. However, in the rest frame of the train it hasn’t moved at all and the distance between these two events is zero! Assuming no accelerations at the start and end of the journey, both frames are equally valid Galilean frames of reference.

My two questions are as follows:

(1) I have not studied special relativity or *mathematical* classical mechanics, but I suppose I am to understand that the Galilean group (symmetries of the space described above) is isomorphic to (or defined as?) the set of valid inertial reference frames?

(2) How am I to understand the reference frame example in the context of the above? I believe Szekeres is pointing out that *if* we allowed distances to be defined between non-simultaneous events, *then* we would find that different reference frames would "compute" different distances between events. **This would, in turn, contradict the axiom of classical mechanics/Galilean relativity that different inertial frames of reference determine the same distances between points.** Is this understanding correct? I have bolded the step which I cannot justify; is this an axiom as stated, does it derive from something I've written above, or is it derivable from something I'm missing?

**Edit:**
I'm adding a "bonus" question (bonus since I don't want to layer on an unrelated question, but it's somewhat related -- feel free to indicate if I should just ask this as a separate question). Szekeres goes on to define the Lorentz group by saying that the space of events has on it a function which encodes the "preservation of the light cone":

> The Galilean transformations do not preserve the light cone at the origin
> $$\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2 = c^2\Delta t^2.$$

Szekeres then goes on to derive a requirement on the form of the symmetry transformations, deriving the structure of the Poincare group thereform. What I am confused about is whether Minkowski space as so defined is to be understood as the same space as Galilean space above (i.e. the 3 functions defined above are still part of the set of functions $\mathcal{F}$ on the space, *and* we also add that the function
$$\Delta s^2 := \Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2 + \Delta z^2 - c^2\Delta t^2$$
must be invariant under the given symmetry transformation. Or are we removing one of the three functions above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Galilean group is the set of transformations from one inertial reference frame to another.
2. It's not so much an axiom as part of the definition of "distance." What we're looking for is a measurable quantity which is the same in all frames of reference. The spatial distance between simultaneous events fits this description; the spatial distance between non-simultaneous events does not. It's not illegal to *talk about* the latter, if you'd like, but since it depends entirely on which reference frame you're calculating it in, it does not have any physical meaning in its own right.
3. We're removing the entire concept of simultaneity. Two events which are simultaneous in one frame are not simultaneous in another.

Comment: Some followups: 1) Does this not mean it's isomorphic to the set of reference frames (if we fix some initial reference frame)? 2) That makes complete sense, thank you! 3) What does that mean for which functions remain in $\mathcal{F}$? As I think about it more, I think it's only function 2 in the Galilean spacetime which gets modified (indeed, it's a special case, when $\Delta t = 0$). I think that the second function maybe gets deleted and the other two remain?

Comment: 1) Isomorphic is a strange word to use. Given some initial inertial reference frame, then yes there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between Galilean transformations and inertial frames. But considering them as the same kind of object does not seem useful. 3) Neither functions 1 nor 2 survive the transition to Minkowski spacetime as frame-independent quantities. Given two events, the time interval between them **and** the spatial distance between them are dependent on the reference frame. In particular, whether they are simultaneous or not is dependent on the frame of reference.

Comment: I see re: (1), thank you. Re: (3), and to confirm, you agree with @LPZ below that the functions which characterize Minkowski spacetime are (1) rectilinear motion (2) the $\Delta s^2$ I wrote at the end of the OP?

Comment: @EE18 I've never seen it put quite that way, but yes, I agree - insofar as rectilinear motion and $\Delta s^2$ are frame-independent.

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted, but if you're able to comment on what you mean by "frame independent" in your last comment, as well as why this is not the standard characterization of Minkowski space.

Comment: @EE18 I mean that (1) given any two events $A$ and $B$, the quantity $\Delta s^2 = (x_B-x_A)^2 + (y_B-y_A)^2 + (z_B-z_A)^2 - c^2 (t_B-t_A)^2$ takes the same value in every reference frame, and (2) if an object is in rectilinear motion in one inertial frame, it is in rectilinear motion in every other inertial frame (though of course it will be traveling with a different velocity). There's nothing non-standard about it, it's just not the terminology I usually see.

Comment: Got you, perfect! The notion of these holding "in every reference frame" is, I think, what motivates the search for the type of transformations (the Poincare group) which preserve these two? At any rate, I really need to study some special relativity. If you have any suggestions there for someone who has never done it but who has some mathematical maturity, I would greatly appreciate it. All the best, and thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

(1) The term isomorphic is not appropriate. A group isomorphism relates two groups that have the same structure. However, the set of inertial frames do not have a natural operation so do not form a group.

The correct mathematical description is that the Galilean transformations have a natural [simple transitive action](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on the inertial frames simply transitive. A typical example is an affine space and its associated vector space. In particular, there are one to one correspondence between the two, but no distinguished one. Intuitively, inertial frames are Galilean transformations up to the identity.

(2) Yes it is correct. Basically, the spatial distance between two events is frame dependent. This is a reformulation of your bolded sentence. The author gives an explicit example of this discrepancy. If you want a more formal example, say you start with a frame $x,t$ and another frame $x’,t’$ related by a Galilean transformation:
$$
\begin{align}
x’&=x-vt\\
t’&=t
\end{align}
$$
The spatial increments between two events $1$ and $2$ are related by:
$$
\begin{align}
d&=x_1-x_2 \\
d’&=x_1’-x_2’\\
&= d+v(t_2-t_1)
\end{align}
$$
so are different iff $t_1\neq t_2$ (not simultaneous).

(Bonus) Yes you remove the 3 functions defining Galilean relativity. You only conserve the spacetime metric. To avoid confusion, I would recommend referring to as Galilean/Minkowski spacetime not just space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Noted on (1) and (2), thank you! With respect to (3), I'm not sure I agree (or at least I don't follow). I think it's only function 2 in the Galilean spacetime which gets modified (indeed, it's a special case, when $\Delta t = 0$). I think that the second function maybe gets deleted and the other two remain? The third function must at least remain, right (from my limited knowledge of SR I believe Newton's first law still holds)? Perhaps function 1 gets deleted?

Comment: Also, I can see that the action is transitive, but why should I see that it's simple (which I'm understanding as no non-trivial normal subgroups)?

Comment: Yes you're right, rectilinear motion is preserved. Actually in SR, you have to view the Minkowski metric as a fusion of distance and time interval. Indeed, you recover the two functions when $c\to\infty$. When the $\Delta t\neq 0$, thanks to the $c$ factor, the partial increment becomes negligible and you recover the first function. When exactly $\Delta t=0$, then you are left with spatial distance, the second function. This is why both are replaced by a unified expression.

Comment: For the free action, it just means that any non trivial Galilean transformation never leaves a frame invariant. This is pretty intuitive if you think about it since they are defined by their action on the frames. If it leaves a frame fixed, then it wouldn't be relevant in the first place, and there would be no way to distinguish it from the identity.

Comment: Your comment about the fusion in the $c\to\infty$ limit is fascinating; thank you so much for pointing that out. If I am to confirm, then there are two preserved functions on Minkowski space: (1) rectilinear motion (2) the Minkowski metric?

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused about what properties the action has. Is "simple" action another term for free action?

Comment: Glad it was insightful. Actually, just as you can see the Galilean group as a degenerate Lorentz group, you can view the Poincaré group as a degenerate de Sitter/Anti-de Sitter group. Check out [this](http://jakobschwichtenberg.com/larger-symmetries/) for a introduction on the topic.

Comment: Yes, there are two preserved functions. I initially dismissed the rectilinear motion because you don’t need them to construct the Lorentz group. If your group preserves the Minkowski metric, then necessarily it is linear so will preserve rectilinear motion.

Comment: Yes, simple transitive means free and transitive (as explained in the linked wikipedia article).

Comment: I've gone with the other answer because of it's answer of (2), but I wanted to say thank you so much for this extremely enlightening discussion, as well as the many other times you've helped me out before.